# can I pop 2 times with stack? (java)

Tags: java, stack

Im writing a program with the help of a stack. I have to decode inputs. for example the word 'he-llo', becomes 'hllo', but I get 'hello'. the '-' should have the effect of deleting the character which comes before it and it self.
I know that I have to use pop (which I have implemented my self), but I have problems with using it twice in a row. Because I've actually already printed the 'e' in the first if statement. I'm really clueless on how to fix this, am I printing it wrong? or should I adapt my pop code?

```
//my pop code
public char pop() {
    if(!this.empty()){
        if(top > 0){
            temp = arr[top - 1];
            arr[top -1] = 0;
            top = top -1;
        }
        return temp;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    //handling the charachters of the input
    if(Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch)){
         Stack.push(ch);    
         System.out.println(myStack.peek());
    }
    if(Stack.peek() == '-'){
         myStack.pop();
         myStack.pop();
         System.out.println(Stack.peek());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a Complete and Verifyable example. We should be able to download and run your code, which we can't right now as we don't see your main method or whatever method you use to set up your stack and call pop().

Comment: Is the only problem you're solving deleting the char before and the minus sign ?

Comment: @nhouser9 oh I'm sorry, my code is way too long to post it here and I dont have permission to do that:(

Comment: @Joey deleting the minus sign goes fine, the character before it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

your question is about using pop twice in a row--yes, that should work as long as top represents at least two objects on the stack

the semantics of Stack is slightly wrong for pop if your implementation is using an array.  the top of stack (top) is supposed to be the object you see; your pop is using top - 1.  secondly, there is no need to set the popped objects to 0, the push method should overwrite the value if the Stack is correctly implemented.

the empty test is not correctly used given the above; empty should test for top < 0 and return true if so, otherwise false.  stack[0] is a legitimate element.  perhaps a bit of review of stacks and their implementation and operations is in order?

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback! I will try to change it